# How can I get LaTeX to reset numbering after 99?

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I am writing a book and it has a lot of footnotes. They go beyond 99 so I have 3-digit footnotes which is awkward. How can I get LaTeX to reset numbering after 99?

Comment: Won't this be confusing? Why don't you restart numbering with each new chapter, for example?

Answer (score 6):

Package [`alphalph`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/alphalph.pdf) supports this kind of numbering via method `wrap`. The following example defines a formatting command `\twodigitwrap`, which wraps the numbering to appear 1 after 99. The footnote value is not changed, just the appearance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\makeatletter
% \@twodigitwrap defines the symbols for \twodigitwrap
\newcommand*{\@twodigitwrap}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<100 %
    \number#1%
  \else
    \@ctrerr
  \fi
}
\newalphalph{\twodigitwrap}[wrap]{\@twodigitwrap}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\twodigitwrap{\value{footnote}}}

\begin{document}
  Lorem\footnote{Lorem}
  ipsum\footnote{ipsum}
  dolor\footnote{dolor}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{94}
  \dots\space
  Donec\footnote{Donec}
  varius\footnote{varius}
  orci\footnote{orci}
  eget\footnote{eget}
  risus\footnote{risus}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the foot note numbering per page or per chapter so that it is not confusing your readers. For per page, you will have to reveal your document class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
  \footnote{Some footnote}
  text here
  \clearpage
  \footnote{Some footnote}
  text here
  \clearpage
  \footnote{Some footnote}
  text here
  \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is some method behind this madness...

Below I've used a string comparison (via `\pdfstrcmp`; requires e-TeX) to check whether the counter stepping is done for the `footnote` counter. If this is the case, another check is performed to reset the counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Taken from latex.ltx and modified
\def\stepcounter#1{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{footnote}=0 % Check if counter is footnote
    \ifnum\value{footnote}=99 % Check if value should be reset
      \setcounter{footnote}{0}% Reset footnote counter
    \fi
  \fi
  \addtocounter{#1}\@ne
  \begingroup
  \let\@elt\@stpelt
  \csname cl@#1\endcsname
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\usepackage[margin=1.5in,paper=a6paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

First\footnote{First}. % 1
Second\footnote{Second}. % 2
\setcounter{footnote}{97}%
Third\footnote{Third}. % 98
Fourth\footnote{Fourth}. % 99
Fifth\footnote{Fifth}. % 1

\end{document}
```